# NPM installs dependencies in a wrong place

Tags: node.js, npm

I just run a simple `npm install morgan` in a folder and for some reason it adds all the sub dependencies to the parent folder. See image attached

[image]

Comment: What version of npm are you using? that looks like the functionality that they were talking about adding to npm 3

Comment: Using 3.3 I believe. They are seriously calling that a feature?

Comment: Yup. I suggest reading up on the changes for it in the beta overview.

Comment: Thank man! I just spend a crazy amount of time thinking something broke or I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Not at a computer to test, but I wouldn't require without it being in package.json either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a new feature in npm 3.x, you can read about it here:

https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0

> Your dependencies will now be installed *maximally flat*. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's `node_modules` folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

Basically, it now handles dependencies with as little nesting as possible.

Comment: This functionality cannot be disabled. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904510/

Answer (score 0):

Npm has changed the way they organize dependencies. So instead of 2 separate modules requiring the same dependency and installing them in their own node_modules folder. The dependency is only installed once at the same folder level the node module is installed at.