# When npm installing GULP in local project - I get a ton of folders in node_modules - why?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I've been following this Gulp install by CSS tricks - https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/  I noticed that when I get to their folder shot of what should be in the node_module folder... they only have bin and gulp.  I have 40+ folders that get added.  **Is this suppose to happen?  Does Gulp need these dependencies?  If not why is it happening?**  Here is my package.json with certain info emitted and a screenshot of 1/2 the folders made on install.  I start the project clean (no folders or crazy installs uninstalls were done).

```
{
  "name": "---",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+-----.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "---",
    "---'",
    "---",
    "---"
  ],
  "author": "-----",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "------",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM installs dependencies in a wrong place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727336/npm-installs-dependencies-in-a-wrong-place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to changes in the new npm 3, which I assume you're using here (you can check by doing `npm -v` if you want to make sure). All modules and their dependencies are now in /node_modules instead of being nested in sub-folders of the module that depended on them (like it used to be).

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting.

Source: http://dailyjs.com/2015/06/26/npm-3/

Comment: Thanks!  I am using NPM 3.5.0.